# How to extract value from nested xml object in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, xml, postgresql

I have an input parameter in postrge function:

```
<File xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" FILE_CREATE="2020-02-17T17:43:55" FILE_NAME="test02.txt"><PPK><InfoP result="123"/></PPK></File>
```

How to extract "123" value using plpgsql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need PL/pgSQL functions for that. You can use pure SQL inside of your function to extract the value you want using the [`xpath`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-xml.html) expression `'//PPK/InfoP/@result'`:

```
SELECT 
(XPATH('//PPK/InfoP/@result', 
  '<File xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     FILE_CREATE="2020-02-17T17:43:55" FILE_NAME="test02.txt">
     <PPK><InfoP result="123"/></PPK></File>'))[1];

 xpath 
-------
 123
(1 Zeile)
```